# Detect Action Cable connection status

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, actioncable

I have a Vue app that connects to a Rails back-end and need to find out whether the connection is established or not.

In my app I do:

```
var app = new Vue({
    name: "Site",
    store,
    router,
    i18n,
    components: {},
    mixins: [],
    data: {
     cable: App.cable
    }
});
```

However `cable.connection.disconnected` is always true even when actually connected.

How can I reliably figure out (when needed) what the connection status is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got it sorted out. In my components, when I need to find out cable status, I do

```
this.$root.cable.connection.isOpen()
```

If false I revert to HTTP.

Hope this helps someone later on.

Answer (score -1):

You can try broadcast some message on server and watch Vue app can receive that message.

Comment: In order for this to work on demand I'd have to hit the server to have it send a message then listen with a timeout in order to figure out the connection is not open. Too complicated.